# SSRS cannot find a new stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that is calling a stored procedure **(sp_Original).** 
I created **(sp_Original_New)** which contains changes.

Both Procedures are in the ***same database*** and ***same server***. Both procedures have **identical permissions**.

I can run both stored procedures with the same parameters and it is bringing back the correct information. I cleared the local cache (Ctr + Shft + R) and everything seems to be working correctly.

The issue is the **SSRS** report throws an error when I try to switch to the new stored procedure stating that the **new stored procedure cannot be found** (Error 2812).

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? The datasource hasn't even been changed because it's going to the exact same place and I am not sure how to force a "refresh" when all the data source has is a connection string.

Comment: Does the account used for the datasource have execute permissions to this proc?

Comment: Keep in mind that even if the proc was created with the same permissions/owner, the SSRS account still may not have access (as @scsimon suggests)

Comment: I will double check permissions. It is using windows authentication so it's using my credentials to run/find both stored procedures.

Comment: Script the SPs out and show us the first line for comparison. I'm suspecting schema might be different. If not, try not only create script but full object script export and compare.